# How to make Windows save files to slave hard drive by default?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a little problem. I have the need to make  Windows save files to the slave hard drive by default. By that i mean that there is some programs that save their data automatically to the hard drive, and by default the hard drive would be the master. I need to change that. Let's say that when i save a file on the desktop, the file will be saved on the slave HD but seen in the desktop anyway. Is this possible to do?

Comment: By "master" do you mean the boot drive, the one on which the operating system is installed?  And by "slave" do you mean a secondary drive?  As written, all you need to do is install Windows to the slave drive (or reverse the positions of the drives) and all will be well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows 7, you can try editing the locations on your "Documents" library, just right click on the library and select Properties.

In the list of locations you can add a new directory located on your slave drive and choose this directory as the default for saving.

Most recent applications will use this data for choosing where to save the files.